# How do I add "using Mysql.data.mysqlclient;" to Monodevelop through Unity? (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, reference, monodevelop

I am trying to make a login/registration system in Unity and Monodevelop using C#, and I can't seem to get using mysql to show up. I have tried installing the connector (here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=455844) which didn't seem to work. I tried looking under Project > Solution Options and haven't found anything.

Comment: Have right clicked your references map clicked edit references and added it through the assets tab?

Comment: I have seen someone else say that on Google but I can't seem to find that on my project. My screen looks like this http://i.imgur.com/90xwnAe.png

How would I get to there from here?

Comment: I fixed it. Go to View > Pads > Solution to add in the solution explorer. Then find the reference tab and right click the wheel and click "Edit References...", then add the references you want.